# How to make a listener that listens for changes in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, listeners, treemap

I'm making a GUI which conjugates Spanish Verbs.  It utilizes a TreeMap as the main data structure, which is filled with instantiations of the class Verb.  Each instantiation includes a String which contains the infinitive form of the Verb, like "hablar" or "escribir."  There's a function in the GUI that allows the user to input a new Verb by typing in its infinitive and its English translation.

I want to know how to create a listener that will run some code every time that a new verb is added -- or removed -- from the TreeMap.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Good question. This seems like something that might be useful. I've don't believe I've seen it before, but you might be able to subclass the class and create your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass the TreeMap class, eg.

```
public class MyTreeMap<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V val) {
        V ret = super.put(key, val);
        myAddCallback(key, val);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(K key) {
        V ret = super.remove(key);
        myRemoveCallback(key);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Another (significantly more involved) option would be to check out [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), an [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)-based JRE.

Comment: @idungotnosn: Look at the oberserver pattern, a base implementation is available in JSE: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

Comment: if there's going to be more complicated logic in the MyTreeMap, I think it is better to use delegation instead of subclassing.